# Reuse decision requirement diagram in another DMN model?

Tags: workflow, drools, jbpm, business-rules

I have a decision requirements diagram called MyDecision1.dmn for example. I want to then import that as a component in another dmn model, MyDecision2.dmn. MyDecision2.dmn should take the output of MyDecision1 and use it as an input. Am I able to do this in the jBPM workbench when editing dmn files?

I see that I can include models; however, instead of getting the entire DRD as a single asset, I only get the individual components and the task of assembling them is left to me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the later versions of KIE bpmn(Process) modeler you can add the DMNs as Activities and use the input output from them.

[image: Processs Modeler with support for DMN DecisionTask]